# Table searches fast on local SQL Server but slow on host SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table that contains about a 100,000 rows, I have setup all the correct indexes and primary keys and Full Text Search and made sure its fine tuned.

I created a stored procedure that searches a nvarchar column in the table, the SP is long and has multiple select / insert statements.

Now when I run the SP on my local SQL Server I get the result in one second, then I backed up the database and restored it on another machine and tried the same search and I  got it in one second.

My problem is when I create the database in my hosts shared SQL Server and import all the data from my SQL Server and run the search I get the result in 7 seconds! although I made sure I have the same indexes and primary keys and FTS working.

The only difference in my database in the hosts sql server is that I created the schema using a script then I imported all the data using the import/export wizard, so to check if this is whats causing this problem I created a new database on my machine and imported the data using the wizard, and I got the search result in 3 seconds!

I checked the execution plan of the SP in the database on the hosts SQL Server and found one index scan is taking 49% of the cost while on my machine it was 0%

Can somebody please point out why this is happening?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Now when I run the execution plan for both servers I get exactly the same plan and costs, but still the speed difference is huge (1 second and 7 seconds).

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure on the Shared Host? from SQL Management Studio or from a web page on your shared host?

Comment: Could you post the query please? If both your local SQL and the Prod server are doing table scans, then your indexing might not be 100%.

Comment: I'm calling the Stored procedure from SQL Management studio and passing the search query. is there a way to check if the table index has a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't solve the strange behavior in SQL Server, I ended up replacing this stored procedure with Full Text Search and it gave a faster result.